# Magento 1.9 Creating new attribute for categories and getting issue for default value in existing categories

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created new attribute (created new module for this) for categories with "Yes / No" drop-down options but during the creations of new category its showing default value (yes) while while checking existing categories its showing "No" in drop-down. So I have to manually go to all categories and update existing categories vaules to Yes.

How I can make drop-down to show "Yes" default for existing categories too.

Please help.

My sql file (mysql4-install-0.0.1.php) during creation of module is below:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'type'                       => 'int',
    'label'                      => 'Include in Body Menu',
    'input'                      => 'select',
    'source'                     => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'default'                    => '1',
    'sort_order'                 => 10,
    'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'group'                      => 'General Information',
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'inclde_body_menu', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this script from browser or from terminal

```
<?php

require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$resource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category');
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();

// here get category collection

foreach($collection as $category) {
    $category->setStoreId(0);    // 0 for default scope (All Store Views)
    $value=1
    $category->setData('inclde_body_menu', $value);
    $resource->saveAttribute($category, 'inclde_body_menu');
}
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Can you please tell me how I can run this from browser. Do I have to create new file in root with your code and open this file.???

Comment: create category.php file and add above code after write in browser like this way `www.example.com/category.php` then check it

Comment: HI Rakesh, This code is not working.

Comment: @AbiSharma this code working for me i have tested this code my side and update boolean attribute

Comment: Actually $collection variable is not defined in above code too...

Comment: ohh i have updated my code please check it

Comment: Yes, Thanks for this code and guidance. its works now, I am checking the website now.